# Celsius to fahrenheit converter

Tags: vb.net

My Celsius to Fahrenheit converter works when converting from Celsius to Fahrenheit but not the other way around.

I think it might have something to do with it doing the math twice, but I'm not sure.

[image: What my program looks like]

Here is my code:

```
Public Class frmConversion
    Private Sub frmConversion_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AcceptButton = btnConvertir
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvertir.Click
        Dim intF As Decimal
        Dim intC As Decimal
        intC = Val(txtbxEntreeC.Text)
        intF = Val(txtbxEntreeF.Text)
        If Me.lblCelsius.Location.Y = 101 And Me.lblCelsius.Location.X = 39 Then
            'Crée un Integer pour Fahrenhei et Celcius
            intF = intC * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
            Me.txtbxEntreeF.Text = intF
        End If
        If Me.lblCelsius.Location.X = 29 And Me.lblCelsius.Location.Y = 202 Then
            intC = (intF - 32) * 5 / 9
            Me.txtbxEntreeF.Text = intC
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSwitch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSwitch.Click
        'if this is F, then we switch the c back to c and the f back to f, otherwise we do the opposite
        If Me.lblCelsius.Location.Y = 101 And Me.lblCelsius.Location.X = 39 Then
            Me.lblCelsius.Location = New Point(29, 202)
            Me.lblFahrenheit.Location = New Point(39, 101)
            txtbxEntreeC.Location = New Point(273, 98)
            txtbxEntreeF.Location = New Point(273, 199)
            txtbxEntreeC.Text = ""
            txtbxEntreeF.Text = ""
        ElseIf Me.lblCelsius.Location.X = 29 And Me.lblCelsius.Location.Y = 202 Then
            Me.lblCelsius.Location = New Point(39, 101)
            Me.lblFahrenheit.Location = New Point(29, 202)
            txtbxEntreeC.Location = New Point(273, 199)
            txtbxEntreeF.Location = New Point(273, 98)
            txtbxEntreeC.Text = ""
            txtbxEntreeF.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think the error might be because the numbers are showing too many decimals. Is there a way to limit the amount of decimals in my textbox?

Comment: Not all real numbers can be accurately represented in decimal form, either because they go on forever (like Pi) or because they repeat forever (like `1/3`).  Additionally, digital computers are limited a fixed number of digits, so even if a particular number can be represented as a decimal, if it contains too many digits, the computer will have to truncate it (i.e. round it).  Therefore, it's quite accurate to say that the vast majority of of real numbers cannot be accurately stored in a single variable.

Comment: For that reason, when you convert one way, and it results in a non-whole number, you can't expect it to exactly convert that back to the original number.  It's almost always going to be slightly off.  The simple solution is to round the results before displaying them.

Comment: It is a simple typo, you display the result in txtbxEntreeF even if the user entered Fahrenheit.

Comment: I wouldn't move the labels and text boxes around. Just change the text of the labels in the Switch button and check the label.text to determine what calculation to do.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     Dim intF As Decimal
>     Dim intC As Decimal
>     intC = Val(txtbxEntreeC.Text)
>     intF = Val(txtbxEntreeF.Text)
> ```

`int` is a [Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) prefix that makes your variables read like they're **int**egers, which they aren't; they're `Decimal`. Drop the Hungarian Notation (heavily discouraged in .NET), and note that `Val` is a legacy function from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace that makes your code read like VB6. Use .NET-idiomatic type casts and conversions instead. `Val` returns a `Double` by the way, so despite the explicit conversion from `String` to `Double`, there's *still* an implicit one going on from `Double` to `Decimal`. Pick a type, stick to it.

> ```
> Me.txtbxEntreeF.Text = intF
> ```

Here the implicit conversion is from `Decimal` to `String`.

> *Is there a way to limit the amount of decimals in my textbox?*

Yes. Make the conversion explicit, and [*format* the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier).

```
Me.txtbxEntreeF.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}", intF)
```

Like I do with VBA UserForm code, I would warmly recommend making a dedicated class for your *model*, to separate the logic from the data. That way you could have a `Decimal` value for each unit of measure, conversion logic encapsulated in one place, and then a form that's only responsible for interacting with this "model" and formatting its properties for display. Form's code-behind has no business implementing the conversion logic itself - look into how the *Model-View-Presenter* UI pattern makes your code more robust.

Please post your **working** code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get feedback and ideas (asking how to do X or how to fix Y on CR is off-topic).